# TinyMCE & CKEditor problem with AJAX & CSS

Tags: css, ajax, jquery, wysiwyg

I'm programming a new free (free speach) web application for managing Medical (clinical) Labs via python, so I used WYSIWYG editors like: tinyMCE, CKEditor and nicEdit. there's no editor worked perfectly except nicEdit (with a trick).

**TinyMCE:** The First Problem is TinyMCE dosen't work when it's requested by jQuery AJAX. it works perfectly in the Main Page. but I've to call `alert()` function to activate it in [the jQuery AJAX Requested page](http://medilab-demo.appspot.com/editors/tinymce). I put two buttons for show and hide TinyMCE but they didn't work unless I call function `alert()`.

The Second Problem is the tools icons is Scattered in the jQuery AJAX Requested Page. while the tools in the main page is good. I don't know the main reason of this problem, AJAX or CSS? **<Solved by removing padding from p, label, span in CSS stylesheet>**

**CKEditor:** The first Problem: CKEditor dosen't work in [the page requested by AJAX](http://medilab-demo.appspot.com/editors/ckeditor), neither I call `alert()` function or not, while it's working good in the main page. I tried to put a button call function `CKEDITOR.replace('textarea_id');` but it didn't work. **<Solved by Changing the CKEDITOR_BASEPATH>**

The Second Problem of CKEditor is like the second problem of TinyMCE! **<Solved by removing padding from p, label, span in CSS stylesheet>**

How can I solve these problems, or can I use another free advanced WYSIWYG editors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading CKEditor in an unexpected way, so it's trying to load the rest of files from a wrong location.

You should uncomment the ckeditor.js like you have the other editors, or you can try to set a global variable [CKEDITOR_BASEPATH](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.basePath) before loading the ckeditor.js file

Comment: Okay, it's solved the first problem of CKEditor but the second Problem isn't solved, it's like the second problem of TinyMCE.

Comment: That's due to your stylesheet: #content p, #content label, #content span {
  
}

Comment: Thank You very Much, this problem is solved. CKEditor Problems is Solved. and the second problem of TinyMCE is solved. and I think that no need to TinyMCE now.